# Remove special character from corpus

Tags: r, rstudio, tm, corpus

I built a data that shows all the terms with punctuation and its frequency. Then im supposed to remove the punctuation's from them and check if there is any punctuation remaining.

```
newpapers1 <- tm_map(newpapers, removePunctuation)

punremove <- function(x){gsub(c('¡'|'¯'),"",x)}
punremove1 <- lapply(newpapers1, punremove)
my.check.func <- function(x){str_extract_all(x, "[[:punct:]]")}
my.check1 <- lapply(newpapers1, my.check.func)
p <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(my.check1)))
p
```

But I still end up with this special character:

```
  Var1 Freq
1    ¡   25
```

Is there a way to write a function to remove all the punctuation's together or a function to remove this?

Edit:
Upon checking the documents the punctuation still exists:

```
> newpapers1[[24]]$content
```

> "This study employs a crosscultural perspective to examine how local
>   audiences perceive and enjoy foreign dramas and how this psychological
>   process differs depending on the cultural distance between the media
>   and the viewing audience Using a convenience sample of young Korean
>   college students this study as predicted by cultural discount theory
>   shows that cultural distance decreases Korean audiences¡¯ perceived
>   identification with dramatic characters which erodes their enjoyment
>   of foreign dramas Unlike cultural discount theory however cultural
>   distance arouses Korean audiences¡¯ perception of novelty which
>   heightens their enjoyment of foreign dramas This study discusses the
>   theoretical and practical implications of these findings as well as
>   their potential limitations"

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the punctuation, like this.

```
newpapers1 <- tm_map(newpapers, removePunctuation)

my.check.func <- function(x){gsub('[[:punct:]]+','',x)}
my.check1 <- lapply(newpapers1, my.check.func)
p <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(my.check1)))
p
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, so when I work with `gsub`, after check the documents, it doesn't remove it..going through them I found this `¡¯` and now im not sire how to remove this:/

Comment: Really! Just used it before posting my answer and see that it does remove them. Could you post a sample of your data?

Comment: How do I post a sample?

Comment: Done, shows a sample from the document im working with. I tried with the `('¡|¯')` but didn't work.

Comment: weird! It is removed in my side. Open this link to see the code working: http://tpcg.io/LQmSRS

Comment: Okayyyy so found my mistake, im referring to the wrong name.

Comment: You need no experience to use the website. Once you open the link you'll see your posted data with the `gsub` function and just click **execute** to see the results.

Comment: Yeah your code works, its just that i cannot use `newpapers1[[24]]$content` as it refers to my code where the special character isnt removed.

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear that. All the best.